# PHP Codeigniter: Passing dynamic form data to a view without having to refetch from the database upon validation errors

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, caching

I am making a basic signup page using PHP Codeigniter.

On the signup page, I ask the user to select from a selection of categories (via a `<select>` html element). These categories are stored in a list in my MySQL Database.

My current method is to fetch this list from the DB when the user calls the function to load the page and then display it to them. However, if the user enter's incorrect data and the page must be reloaded with the validation errors, the variable that holds the data in the list seems to be cleared, and I must refetch the list data from the database before redisplaying the page.

I believe there's something in the documentation about how to set this variable to be permanently available but upon looking again, I had no luck in finding it.

Could anyone possibly point me in the right direction? It seems silly to me to have to need to refetch this data every time (I know that people won't be putting in wrong info often, but this will come in handy in a few situations).

NOTE: This is not an issue regarding remembering user selections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this example is for a select drop down list using ci form helper
(i'm modifying this from another form so hopefully its all correct)

```
the Array of select values is: $categoryarray
the drop down field name is 'category'
the default value is $defaultcategory
a css class to style (bootstrap etc): $dropclass = 'class="input-medium"';
```

the line of code is:

```
  form_dropdown('category',$categoryarray,set_value('category',$defaultcategory),$dropclass).form_error('category');
```

the form_error('category'); at the end is for showing a validation error message
and even though there is a default value - if the form fails validation from another field in the form - this will 'remember' what the user selected.

EDIT !

ok there is good and bad news. 
bad news - if the categories are coming from a database then you need to get them again. 
good news - CI remembers what category the user selected from the drop down list.

and the bad news actually isn't that big a deal - if you create the category array in your model. then its just one line of code to add to the validation.

```
// In the Model 

    function makedropdown() {

// get your category list 
$cats = $this->getAllCategories() ;

$categoryarray = array();

   // make the array 
 foreach ( $cats->result() as $row ) {

 $categoryarray[$row->category] =  $row->category ; }

return $categoryarray ;

}
```

someone has filled out the form, we run validation, validation fails. in the controller:

```
if ( $this->form_validation->run($formrules) == FALSE ) {

// get the categoryarray
$data['categoryarray'] = $this->categorymodel->makedropdown() ; 

// load form again
$this->load->view( 'myform', $data ); }
```

So even though we are getting the categories again from the db to dynamically populate the select list - CI still remembers the users choice from the first time they did the form.

And what about a default category for the drop down? if its not going to change then it can be set as a config. if the category values are coming from a database and they can change - then the default category could be created in the model.

EDIT 2

gosh i always do this anyway so why didnt i think of it for this. so yeah this is yet another reason to make a specific method for showing your view

```
 function _showCategoryForm(){

 // get the categoryarray
$data['categoryarray'] = $this->categorymodel->makedropdown() ; 

// anything else thats needed for the view 

// load form view
$this->load->view( 'myform', $data ); }
```

NOW we dont have any repeated code, and its easy to customize the validation failure with an error message if needed.

```
// since i'm grinding on this - the validation should happen in a model 
// and that method returns true or false
if ( $this->somemodel->validateCategoryForm() == FALSE ) {

// custom obnoxious error message 
$this->formerrormessage = "What part of required is eluding you?" ;

$this->_showCategoryForm() ;  }
```

**This is much better because if the needs of your form changes - the change is only in one place.** Also i added an underscore to remind us all that private methods are a good practice. And the form validation should be separate in a model, that is called by the controller.

Comment: So will `$this->fuzzywuzzy` retain its state, even after a call of the controller's constructor?

Comment: thats what i was calling the model, you are asking about $categoryarray - i think that ci will repopulate the select drop down if there is validation error but - try it out and let us know.

Comment: This is where the CI documentation falls short in my opinion. There's little mention of exactly what happens when their functions are used. I had already implemented what you said, but it seems that a new instance of the constructer is created with every new call to it. I put some code in the constructor to indicate this and it printed after every method call that was invoked by the user from the browser via a URI. This means that `$this->load->model(fuzzywuzzy)` will be called every time.

Comment: well definitely the constructor will be called again. thats actually a very very good thing if you need to check credentials before going further. but the form validation is going to be in a completely separate method from the initial showing of the form. i just am not sure if the drop down values would be retained. now you have me curious so if you do not post i will test it myself.

Comment: OK so my implementation is exactly as you have above. Any model state that you set is reset after the user reloads the page so the dropdown values will not be retained (so yes you need to re-fetch the list after the validation method is called). I don't think there's a way around this except to set those values as a config as you say.

Comment: note that there might be a way of passing the $categoryarray with the form - so then it would be available again. but overall this is probably the clearest way to do it. thanks again for asking the question i'm sure i will need to do this at some point.

Comment: I could set it as part of the $_SESSION array no?

Comment: so i would argue against session because its more code and it means the user has to have cookies. but check out my second edit - that is the way to do it, and i have found that having methods just for showing the view can really save a lot of time. in this case its definitely the best. if your get category array method changes, its only in one place now.

Comment: OK but isn't this still requiring a refetch from the DB?

Comment: yes it is. just keep in mind that if you put it in a session - then it will not work at all for people with security software that blocks cookies.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set it as the default value, for example

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="<?php isset($_POST['username']) echo $username;?>" />
```

That way, `$_POST['username']` will always be available.